# Are there known issues with navigator.onLine on Android 2.1?

Tags: android, offline

Are there known issues with navigator.onLine on Android 2.1?  I have a Droid on airplane mode, but navigator.onLine appears to be returning true anyway.  (I'm using an HTML manifest to cache the page, and its behavior works fine in Mobile Safari and Firefox in offline mode.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes as far as I've been able to tell, navigator.onLine always returns true on Droid 2.1. I think that this issue has been addressed in 2.2 along with a number of other offline-related APIs including a new navigator.connection enumeration of connection types, navigator.connection.type for the current connection in use, plus "ononline" and "onoffline" events.

[Short description of this can be found here](http://www.mobilexweb.com/blog/android-froyo-html5-accelerometer-flash-player)